# Dynamic Filter With Typescript in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, filter

I need to use filter to typescript, however, I need to pass a dynamic column, so I can use these methods elsewhere.

That's my job.

```
adcionarLista(selecionados: any, lista: any) {
    const dados = [];
    for (const selecao of selecionados) {
      dados.push(lista.value.filter((v: any) => v.idRelatorio === selecao));
    }
    return dados;
  }
```

due to the part (v.idRelatorio), the code is leaded to only one file.

And I would like to do it like this:

let's say i want to do my condition through the name column;

```
adcionarLista(selecionados: any, list: any: field: any) {
    const dados = [];
    for (const select of selecionados) {
      dados.push(list.value.filter((v: any) => v.field === select));
    }
    return dados;
  }
```

In this example above I would check if the value of the column name is equal to the select.

But if at another time I pass the age value in the field, then the field would already assume that it would look for the age column.

Comment: fundamental advice: use English for your programming career :)

Answer (score 0):

```
adcionarLista(selecionados: any, lista: any, field: string) {
  const dados = [];
  for (const selecao of selecionados) {
    dados.push(lista.value.filter((v: any) => v[field] === selecao));
  }
  return dados;
}
```